# File libsc68.dylib is missing?

Tags: java, build, game-engine

I am trying to run Lionheart Remake under Mac OS, but there is a missing file and it does not want to start. I did Maven build and it produces the JAR file of the game.

Can you tell me how to obtain libsc68.dylib file?

This is the error which I get when I run the JAR:

`java -jar lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar`

```
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Class resources = com.b3dgs.lionheart.AppLionheartPc
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Load library: sc68
Exception in thread "main" com.b3dgs.lionengine.LionEngineException: Error on loading SC68 Library: sc68
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.audio.sc68.Sc68Format.loadLibrary(Sc68Format.java:87)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.audio.sc68.Sc68Format.<init>(Sc68Format.java:103)
    at com.b3dgs.lionheart.AppLionheartPc.main(AppLionheartPc.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'sc68': Native library (darwin/libsc68.dylib) not found in resource path ([file:/Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master/lionheart-pc/target/lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar])
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:303)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:427)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:569)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:544)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.audio.sc68.Sc68Format.loadLibrary(Sc68Format.java:81)
    ... 2 more
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Starting sequence: com.b3dgs.lionheart.Loading
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Ending sequence: com.b3dgs.lionheart.Loading
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Starting sequence: com.b3dgs.lionheart.Scene
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Loading collision formulas from: file:/Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master/lionheart-pc/target/lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar!/com/b3dgs/lionheart/levels/swamp/formulas.xml
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: Loading collision groups from: file:/Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master/lionheart-pc/target/lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar!/com/b3dgs/lionheart/levels/swamp/collisions.xml
12/30/19 5:50 PM  SEVERE: 
com.b3dgs.lionengine.LionEngineException: [effect] Invalid directory: 
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.MediaDefault.getMedias(MediaDefault.java:284)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.game.feature.Factory.createCache(Factory.java:172)
    at com.b3dgs.lionheart.World.prepareCache(World.java:192)
    at com.b3dgs.lionheart.World.loading(World.java:210)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.game.feature.WorldGame.loadFromFile(WorldGame.java:163)
    at com.b3dgs.lionheart.Scene.load(Scene.java:118)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.graphic.engine.Sequence.start(Sequence.java:215)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.graphic.engine.Loader.handle(Loader.java:100)
    at com.b3dgs.lionengine.graphic.engine.Loader.lambda$start$0(Loader.java:62)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
12/30/19 5:50 PM    INFO: LionEngine terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing describes an incomplete piece of software. [Searching around](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=game+library+sc68), it looks like `sc68` refers to a music player or audio library.

Here's the root issue:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'sc68': Native library (darwin/libsc68.dylib) not found in resource path ([file:/Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master/lionheart-pc/target/lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar])`

This says that `darwin/libsc68.dylib` was not found. It's looking inside the path `/Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master/lionheart-pc/target/lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar` which is the jar itself that you're running.

It's possible that there are other files present in the `lionheart-remake-master` directory, and perhaps one of these is the `sc68` library. You could try this, maybe it will find a match:

```
find /Users/todorbalabanov/Desktop/lionheart-remake-master -name 'libsc68.dylib'
```

If it does find a match, then you might be able to make things work by altering how you're running the program. If it does not, then either contact whoever distributes that game, or look for a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The file libsc68.dylib is Mac OS dynamic library for Atari ST and Amiga music. The problem is that this library is native. It is not Java library. It is not distributed with the game itself. I did install sc68 on my Mac like this: "brew install sc68". After that I did search for the file in all folders, like this: "find / -name libsc68.dylib". The file was not found. The name of this file was not found in Google search. that is why I am asking here. For Linux users there is libsc68-devel, but I am trying to run under Mac.

Comment: Yes. I have opened an issue ticket in the project page. Also I have built successfully the Android version. It ran, but it has too many issues on the device which I have used to test it.

Comment: Homebrew installs things at `/usr/local`, so you could run this to find the full path: `find /usr/local -name libsc68.dylib`. From there, you could either put a copy of that .dylib file somewhere that the program is looking, or find a way to tell the program to look at the actual path.

Comment: I have found that Maven embeds this library for Windows and Linux in the following directories: "lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar/win32-x86-64/sc68.dll" and "lionheart-pc-0.0.17.jar/linux-x86-64/libsc68.so", but there is no Mac OS folder.

Comment: I filed a bug on the project page https://github.com/b3dgs/lionheart-remake/issues/217